# Override clean method to clean custom date field so it can accept month/year only or year only date data

Tags: python, django

I want to display and save date data as one of the following forms:

- year-month-day
- year-month
- year

To achieve this, I have the following model structure:

I have a `Model` with following structure

```
CHOICES = [
    (0, "Year/Month/Date"),
    (1, "Year/Month"),
    (2, "Year"),
]

class MyModel(Model):
    my_date = Models.DateField(...)
    my_date_format = Models.SmallIntegerField(choices=CHOICES)
```

And in the `ModelForm`

```
class MyForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
    model = MyModel
    widgets = {"my_date": SelectDateWidget(required=False), }
```

My logic is as follows:

- If user sets day, month and year; then save the date as is and set `my_date_format` to 0.
- If user sets month and year (leave day blank); then I will set day to 1 and set `my_date_format` to 1, so I will ignore day part of my_date data afterwards.
- If user sets year (leave day and month blank ); then I set day and month to 1 and set  `my_date_format` to 2, so I will ignore day and month part of my_date data afterwards.

My problem is with form validation. [SelectDateWidget](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/forms/widgets/#django.forms.extras.widgets.SelectDateWidget) needs to validate date and coerce it to python `datetime.date` but I need the data as it was posted to check which field is blank to set `my_date_format` value.

I have to save date data as `date` to my database so I can query it correctly.

How should I override `form.clean()` method?

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/forms/validation/#cleaning-a-specific-field-attribute

Answer (score 0):

I would try something like that.

Disclaimer: not tested but maybe it can provides ideas to you.

```
def clean(self):
    cleaned_data = super(MyForm, self).clean()

    # Check the my_date_format value here
    ...

    # Then generate appropriate datetime according your own rules
    my_datetime = ...

    # Add datetime to the cleaned_data dictionnary
    cleaned_data['my_date'] = my_datetime

    return cleaned_data
```